# Is the phrase “Ya, boss” an insult?

Tags: phrases, slang

The phrase, “ Ya, boss,” is a senior executive’s response to his direct subordinates on occasion.  Executive is male, subordinates are female. Aside from the fact that the supervisor thinks he is being playful or light hearted, it sounds inappropriate.  Is it more of an insult?

Comment: This is going to essentially opinion based. Some people are more easily insulted than others. Personally, I'd just be bemused if someone said "Ya, boss" to me cos it don't mean a thing 'round here.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'ya, boss' is used as an informal method to acknowledge or respond. It might not be an insult. Some other phrases are 'Done boss' or 'supp boss'. It's a common use of the phrase by the superior to their subordinates and sometimes even vice versa. But the situation and the expression showed also play a vital role in understanding the true nature of the phrase.